# python import object using import as

Tags: python

When I try to use the imported `__version_info` in the default arguments it fails, any ideas how should I refer to it?

```
from sys import version_info as __version_info

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name = "pepe" if __version_info[0] < 3 else "jose"):
        self.name = name
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jose/Documents/Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Foo:
File "/home/jose/Documents/Test.py", line 5, in Foo
    def __init__(self, name = "pepe" if __version_info[0] < 3 else "jose"):
NameError: name '_Foo__version_info' is not defined
```

Comment: All names that start with `__` inside a class body are changed during compilation time to `_classname__variablename`, hence it is looking for `_Foo__version_info` in your case.  Try with a single underscore: `_version_info`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks for the tip that was it